# when i tried to use "pip install locust" command on Windows 10 error happened

Tags: pip, locust

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'd:\py\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tf1pv8t2\Confi
gArgParse\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tf1pv8t2\ConfigArgParse\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'
open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-i
nfo
cwd: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tf1pv8t2\ConfigArgParse
Complete output (36 lines):
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\py\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init*_.py", line 2857, in get_entry_map
ep_map = self.*ep_map
File "d:\py\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources_*init**.py", line 2815, in **getattr**
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _ep_map**

Comment: what am i supposed to do...

Comment: looks like that is just part of the error message?